# [Linux | Cscore]avutil-55 DllNotFoundException

Tags: c#, linux, cscore

I am trying to run my application which uses cscore (https://github.com/filoe/cscore) and its sub namespace "CSCore.Ffmpeg"

I've already tried what the author explained in "https://github.com/filoe/cscore/blob/master/CSCore.Ffmpeg/Readme.md" ('LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./ mono MyApp.exe') without success.

My question would be how to get it working on Debian 9 using mono. 
Additionally i would be grateful if anyone could tell me where i could get the required libraries for my operating system.

This is the stacktrace:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'CSCore.Ffmpeg.FfmpegCalls' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'CSCore.Ffmpeg.FfmpegUtils' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: avutil-55
at (wrapper managed-to-native) CSCore.Ffmpeg.Interops.ffmpeg:av_log_set_callback (intptr)
at CSCore.Ffmpeg.FfmpegCalls.SetLogCallback (CSCore.Ffmpeg.FfmpegCalls+LogCallback callback) [0x00006] in <117ca019c81b40cf9cc0852c6d0ddec3>:0
at CSCore.Ffmpeg.FfmpegUtils..cctor () [0x00025] in <117ca019c81b40cf9cc0852c6d0ddec3>:0
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at CSCore.Ffmpeg.Interops.InteropHelper.RegisterLibrariesSearchPath (System.String path) [0x00012] in <117ca019c81b40cf9cc0852c6d0ddec3>:0
at CSCore.Ffmpeg.FfmpegCalls..cctor () [0x0008f] in <117ca019c81b40cf9cc0852c6d0ddec3>:0
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at CSCore.Ffmpeg.AvFormatContext..ctor (System.String url) [0x00006] in <117ca019c81b40cf9cc0852c6d0ddec3>:0
at CSCore.Ffmpeg.FfmpegDecoder..ctor (System.String url) [0x00029] in <117ca019c81b40cf9cc0852c6d0ddec3>:0
at AudioTool.AudioClient.AudioStart (System.String url) [0x00001] in <57d1cee9c20047c6a0c5acfeeccbf254>:0
at AudioTool.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00038] in <57d1cee9c20047c6a0c5acfeeccbf254>:0
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Solved issue by installing the appropriate linux packages and copying the libraries from '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/' into the folder where the application is.

After that i had to look what mono expects by setting the mono loglevel to debug (LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./ MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug mono MyApp.exe)
An error appeared (something like Mono: DllImport error loading library '/root/bot/Debug/libavutil-55.so': '/root/bot/Debug/libavutil-55.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
)

Then i renamed the existing libavutil.so.55 to libavutil-55.so,I repeated that for every missing include and mono accepted that.
I hope that helps everyone who has a similar problem in future.